# Excel VBA: how do I copy a range to an array as text?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of cells (custom format) filled with time data (e.g. 8:00, 7:30, 5:45, ...) as text to write to another program through Application.SendKeys. When I grab the cells as they are, they're written out as e. g. 1.041666666 instead of 7:30. How do I copy or convert them to text? Trying to get the value/text from the whole range as I copy won't work, neither did attempts at looping through afterwards to change the values separately. There might be workarounds using clipboard, but I want to leave it untouched. Code right now:

```
DayArray = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E4")

For j = 1 To UBound(DayArray)
    For k = 1 To 5 'fixed column count
        DayArray(j, k)= DayArray(j, k).Text
        Next k
    Next j
 
(... SendKeys example)
Application.SendKeys DayArray(1, 1), True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Format()` Function.  It returns a string in the format desired:

```
DayArray = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E4")

For j = 1 To UBound(DayArray)
    For k = 1 To 5 'fixed column count
        DayArray(j, k)= Format(DayArray(j, k),"h:mm")
    Next k
Next j
```

Answer (score 2):

### Time Range to Strings in a 2D one-based Array

Try:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim DayArray() As Variant: DayArray = ws.[TEXT(A1:E4,"h:mm")]
```

or just (for the `ActiveSheet` exclusively):

```vb
Dim DayArray() As Variant: DayArray = [TEXT(A1:E4,"h:mm")]
```

Or an `Evaluate` one-liner function...

```vb
Function GetTimeRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    GetTimeRange = rg.Worksheet.Evaluate("TEXT(" & rg.Address & ",""h:mm"")")
End Function
```

... to be used e.g. in the following way:

```
Sub GetTimeRangeTEST()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1:E4")
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetTimeRange(rg)
    ws.Range("G1").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
End Sub
```